# Find and refresh treeview from popup window

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, find, element

I've got a problem.  I use TreeView in my WPF project to visualize my XML data. The TreeView is in UserControl and linked to main grid. The problem is, when I edit my XML data in popup window, i can't find treeView (element by name) to refresh it.

Please help me.

Thank you

**WPF MainWindow:**

```
...
 ...
<Grid>
<uc:UserControlTreeView/>
</Grid>
...
...
```

**UserControl:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlTreeView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="MyList" x:Name="MyList" Source="d:/a/library.xml" XPath="Libraries/*"/>


        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Library" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}"></TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Batch" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}"></TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <TreeView  x:Name="libraryTree"  VerticalAlignment="Top" AllowDrop="True" TreeViewItem.Expanded="TreeViewItem_Expanded" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyList}}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="TestMenu">
            </ContextMenu>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False"/>
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" Handler="OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown" />
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TreeView>
</UserControl>
```

**and pupup window's code:**

XmlElement root = docx.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode element = root.SelectSingleNode("/Libraries/Library[@Name='Pics']");

```
    XmlElement child = docx.CreateElement("Batch");

    child.SetAttribute("Name", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fname));
    child.SetAttribute("Type", "Batch");
    child.SetAttribute("Path", fname);

    element.AppendChild(child);
    docx.Save("d:/a/library.xml");

    TreeView tr = (TreeView)Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("libraryTree");
    //TreeView tr = (TreeView)this.Owner.FindName("libraryTree");
    tr.Items.Refresh();
    tr.UpdateLayout();
```

But tr is still null :(

Comment: Quick and dirty approach could be to implement a public method in MainWindow for refreshing the tree view (which should be able access the TreeView by its private variable name).

But, as long as only file-system uri's are concerned, a much better approach would be to do something similar as explained in this blog: [WPF - Updating XmlDataProvider when source XML changes](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2008/03/wpf_updating_xmldataprovider_w.html).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot travel up or down the visual tree using a popup because popups are not part of the Visual Tree. Same goes with DataBinding, popup will not inherit the binding from the tree.

I have used `Josh Smith's DataContextSpy` class/example to instanciate parts of the bindings that are needed for the popup and assign it to the popup as a `StaticResource`. Then in the popup you manipulate the DataContext directly, which indirectly manipulates other peices of the application (in your case -the visual tree).

Or you can choose to expose parts of your controls as public properties methods and allow for tighter coupling between them..